# Is there a name for abstract pattern with lots of parallel lines and subtle curves?

Tags: patterns, terminology, style-identification

Sort of like a spirograph? Like that old Mistify screensaver for windows. I feel like it shows up a lot as an abstract shape in the background of things.

Trying to think of the best way to make one myself or the best search terms to dig up some photshop brushes (I tried wireframe and spirograph with a few good results). I want a sort of pattern that is similar that could run along a straight edge and fade away (by being less dense) away from it.

[image: mistify screensaver]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should search Guilloché (Guilloche) if it's not digital smoke you looking for.

Comment: Guilloche is definitely the term as Daniel pointed out, I do want to share a great Illustrator plugin that can help make these patterns.. it is a lot of fun actually:
http://rufus.deuchler.net/2010/08/how-to-create-intricate-guillloch%C3%A9-patterns-in-adobe-illustrator.html

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's an official name for it but line morphs fit the description. If you take it a bit further with gradients instead of line strokes, you can call it [digital smoke](http://www.google.com/images?q=digital+smoke&um=1&ie=UTF-8&source=og&sa=N&hl=en&tab=wi&biw=1359&bih=841).

Comment: It's like a wireframe of digital smoke!